# R: Using time series data with 'splinefun' and ggplot2 'stat_function'

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, spline, stat

I have time series data with one observation at each respective time. I run it through R's `splinefun` to create a spline function for the observations. I would like to plot this spline function in `ggplot2` using `stat_function`. I would like for my plot to have date/time as the X axis, instead of the indexed-by-row X axis. Suffice it to say that I've tried many things, from editing the result of `splinefun` (to try to make it work with as.POSIXct), to throwing different aesthetics at the ggplot command.

How do I get the dates/times on the X-axis?

Here is my current plot:

[image]

Here is a reprex:

```
library(ggplot2)

DateTime <- seq.POSIXt(from = as.POSIXct('2020-01-10'),
                       to = as.POSIXct('2020-01-12'),
                       by = '1 hour')
set.seed(1)
y <- runif(length(DateTime), min = 0.5) * cos(as.numeric(DateTime))

df <- data.frame(DateTime = DateTime, 
                 x = seq(1:length(DateTime)),
                 y = y)

myspline <- splinefun(df$x, df$y)

ggplot(mapping = aes(x=1:nrow(df))) +
    stat_function(fun = myspline, size = 1, args = list(deriv = 0))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `splinefun` function seems to work just fine with POSIXct values for me

```
set.seed(1)

df <- transform(data.frame(DateTime = seq.POSIXt(from = as.POSIXct('2020-01-10'),
                                       to = as.POSIXct('2020-01-12'),
                                       by = '1 hour')),
  y=runif(length(DateTime), min = 0.5) * cos(as.numeric(DateTime)))


library(ggplot2)
myspline <- splinefun(df$DateTime, df$y)

ggplot(df, mapping = aes(x=DateTime)) +
  stat_function(fun = myspline, size = 1, args = list(deriv = 0))
```

[image]

Tested with R version 3.6.2

Comment: Looks like this works only if DateTime remains an object in the global environment. In the my non-reprex code I don't have a separate vector with DateTime. In other words, I was assuming the mapping command in ggplot was pulling DateTime from the stat_function somehow... but instead its pulling it from the global environment?

Comment: Well, you never seemed to pass your data.frame to `ggplot` originally. I've updated to an example that doesn't have a global variable and properly passes the data.frame to ggplot for plotting